# Interpretation of the analyticity of $Log(z^3)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to determine the domain over which $Log[z^3]$ is analytic, where $z = x+iy$ (is a complex number).
I understand $Log(w)$ is NOT analytic for $z^3 \in (-\infty,0]$.

With this, and with $\operatorname{\mathbb{R}e}(z^3) = x^3-3xy^2$ and $\operatorname{\mathbb{I}m}(z^3) = i(y^3-3yx^2)$, we know that $Log(z^3)$ is NOT analytic for $z$ such that $x^3-3xy^2\leq 0$ and $\sqrt{3}x=y$.
As such, $Log(z^3)$ IS analytic when $x^3-3xy^2 > 0$, and $x\sqrt{3} \neq y$.
This is where I get a little confused... if I plot the regions where the function is analytic, I essentially get the attached sketch (pardon the crude illustration), where the black "clover leaves" are where $Log(z^3)$ is analytic, and everything white is where the function is not. The leaves would have infinite extent, but the Power Point triangles are the best I've got at the moment. Is this a proper interpretation of the above conditions, assuming they are right? I may have done something wrong, or am misunderstanding something! Any help or confirmation would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the link, I do not know how to get the image to pop up in the post! Sorry about that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx8pj.png

> `[Sketch over which $Log(z^3)$ is analytic, where black regions are analytic regions, and white are not.][1]image`

Comment: The complement of " $x^3-3xy^2\le 0$ and $x \sqrt 3= y$"  is " $x^3-3xy^2>0$ **OR** $x\sqrt 3 \ne y$". Anyway, using the cartesian form of $z$ is a very bad idea. The problem is almost trivial if you use the polar form of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

- As you already said, when we consider the principal branch of the logarithm
  \begin{align*}
  \mathrm{Log(z)}=\ln|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)\qquad\qquad -\pi <Arg(z)\leq \pi\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
  it is the slit-plane
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]}
  \end{align*}
  which gives us the *range of analyticity* of the Log function. We can equivalently state this range as
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\,:\,-\pi < \mathrm{Arg}(z) <\pi\}}
  \end{align*}
  where we exclude from $\mathbb{C}$ the branchpoint $0$ and the negative real axis in terms of the argument of $z$.
- Now we consider the composition of the Log function with the power function $z\mapsto z^3$. We know the polynomial $z^3$ is an entire function so that its range of analyticity is $\mathbb{C}$. We can take therefore every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ which is *not mapped* to the slit $(-\infty, 0]$.

  When $z=re^{i\theta}$ orbits round an origin-centered circle, $z^3=r^3e^{i3\theta}$ does this with three times the angular speed. We therefore have to exclude from the valid arguments of $z$ the three values $-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\pi$ resulting in
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\,:\,\mathrm{Arg}(z)\in \left(-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
  \cup\left(-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
  \cup\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\pi\right)\right\}}
  \end{align*}
  as range of analyticity of $\mathrm{Log}(z^3)$.